# SQLAlchemy filter and join: How to improve performance in a large database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a flask website which lets you search through around 2000 different articles.

I wanted to let people filter the articles by occurences of words. So I went through all of the articles and saved all the words in a table called Wordstat.
I recorded every word that occurs more than 5 times and save the exact count of the word and one quote where it occurs. So ideally I would like that somebody could enter up to 4 words and find all articles where ALL of those 4 words occur more than five times, provide the number of occurrences and quotes fore each words and put everything in a table.

I am relatively new to SQL but eventually found a way to do so. But so far it is just much slower than I would like. So far a single search of just one word takes up to 2 seconds (around 500 results). Is there anything I can do to improve that? I actually thought that I could manage to provide this information pretty instantaneous using SQL. Am I just mistaken? Or is my code just not efficient enough? Is there a better way to do the query? Do I need to model it differently?

I am happy about any ideas that could help me improve it.

A simplified version of my code:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    dbid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False) 
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    words = db.relationship("Wordstat", backref="article_ref")

class Wordstat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    word = db.Column(db.String)
    count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    quote = db.Column(db.String)
    ref_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Article.dbid"))

def filterArticles():
    searched_title = "title"
    searchterms = ["word1", "word2"]
    content_filter = [Wordstat.word == term for term in searchterms]
    stmt = db.session.query(Wordstat.ref_id, func.count('*').label("wrd_count"),\
        func.sum(Wordstat.count).label("occurrences"), func.array_agg(Wordstat.quote).label("quotes")).\
            filter(or_(*content_filter)).group_by(Wordstat.ref_id).subquery()     
            
    articles = db.session.query(Article, stmt.c.occurrences, stmt.c.quotes).\
        join(stmt, Article.dbid == stmt.c.ref_id).\
            filter(and_(stmt.c.wrd_count == len(searchterms)),\
                and_(Article.title = searched_title))
    
    return articles.all()

items = filterArticles()
table = itemTable(items)
return table
```

Comment: Where did you see that `content_filter` syntax?  As near as I can tell, that's going to result in `content_filter` having the value `[False, False]`.

Comment: I can't quite remeber where I found to write it that way but it actually works. It results in a list of `sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression objects`, not in a list of booleans